# Canvas For loop line

Tags: javascript, for-loop, canvas

I am trying to loop round a statement that draws a vertical line through the canvas and was wondering why this doesn't work:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var x = 26;

    ctx.moveTo(26,0);
    ctx.lineTo(26,350);
    ctx.stroke();

    for (var i = 0; i > 27; i++) {
        x = x + 25; 
        ctx.moveTo(x,0);
        ctx.lineTo(x,350);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i > 27; i++)
```

Is being interpreted as "i = 0; as long as i is **greater than** 27, run this, and increment i.

Because 0 is not greater than 27, this would never run.

You're most likely looking for:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 27; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

your for loop is checking if i is greater than 27, and if it isn't it ends. Because it is set to 0, it ends immediately. If you flip the sign from greater than to less than, it stripes the canvas.

https://jsfiddle.net/j6nucv6o/

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var x = 26;

ctx.moveTo(26,0);
ctx.lineTo(26,350);
ctx.stroke();

for (var i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
    x = x + 25; 
    ctx.moveTo(x,0);
    ctx.lineTo(x,350);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```